# Spring boot upgrade : Hibernate SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.String' with right 'java.lang.Integer'

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

Hello I am upgraded my application to  spring boot 3.2.1 .. This application was previously working and the table and the syntax of these queries were unaltered during the upgrade ..
When I run the application I see queries that try to insert into the text-se column throws the below error .. Could you help me understand what am I missing here , I am not using any specific dilects and I fail to understand what the issue is

I am using Spring boot 3.2.1 and Java 21

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: d2
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/abc;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    name:
    username:
    poolName: AbcConnectionPool
    initializationFailTimeout: -1
  jpa:
    database: H2
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.show_sql: true
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create-drop #update #create-drop
      hibernate.import_files_sql_extractor: org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.MultiLineSqlScriptExtractor
  flyway:
    # Before enabling set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
    enabled: false
```

As you see this query works

```
Hibernate: INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group) VALUES('30', '', 'ADDING_PAR', 'Add par', 'Lägg', 'SWITCH_NAME')
```

This also works

```
    Hibernate: INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group) VALUES('30', '', 'PRIVATE_NAME', 'Update private', 'Uppdatera', 'SWITCH_NAME')
```

While this gives an error , because of the text-se field

```
    Hibernate: INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)
    2024-01-25T13:23:24.654+02:00  WARN 21372 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)[*]"; expected "OVERRIDING USER VALUE, OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE, DIRECT, DEFAULT VALUES, VALUES, SET, WITH, (, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES";]
    
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)[*]"; expected "OVERRIDING USER VALUE, OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE, DIRECT, DEFAULT VALUES, VALUES, SET, WITH, (, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES";]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applyScript(Helper.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportFiles(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:665) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:584) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        at ...$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    
    Hibernate: VALUES('20', '1', 'Who is your customer', 'Who is your customer', 'Vem är din kund', 'B098', 'Vi kan inte identifiera kunden. Kan du återkomma med mer information om namn, adress och person-/organisagatuinnummer. Observera personnumret måste vara komplett inklusive de fima sigta siffrorma i personnumrram.')
    Hibernate: INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)
    2024-01-25T13:23:24.664+02:00  WARN 21372 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)[*]"; expected "OVERRIDING USER VALUE, OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE, DIRECT, DEFAULT VALUES, VALUES, SET, WITH, (, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES";]
```

There are values that are inserted fine , only a few are not inserted it expected "OVERRIDING USER VALUE, OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE, DIRECT, DEFAULT VALUES, VALUES, SET, WITH, (, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES";] , which is a bit strange ,This is the table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `code_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `code_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_en` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_se` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_group` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_en` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_se` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=476 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO code_table (type, code, name, description_en, description_se, code_group, text_se)`: where is the rest of this command? There are no values to insert.

Comment: Its in the provided stack trace.. Hibernate: VALUES('20', '1', 'Who is your customer', 'Who is your customer', 'Vem är din kund', 'B098', 'Vi kan inte identifiera kunden. Kan du återkomma med mer information om namn, adress och person-/organisagatuinnummer. Observera personnumret måste vara komplett inklusive de fima sigta siffrorma i personnumrram.')

Answer (score 0):

New line character was the issue .. INSERT INTO and VALUES were in two seperate lines .. while this worked with spring 2.2,